# Do i need to filter my variable before selecting something from database with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a variable `$Search` and i want this query

```
$sel=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username LIKE '%{:src}%'");
$sel->bindValue(":src",$Search);
$sel->execute();
```

I wanted to know if it's safe for me to do this query without doing any filtration on user's input.

Comment: That won't work as it will end up as `'%{':src'}%'`

Comment: it should be `$sel->bindValue(":src",'%'.$Search.'%');`. and your query should be `$sel=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username LIKE :src");` And yes, it will be safe.

Comment: Or you can do `LIKE CONCAT('%', :src, '%')` and bind it like you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepared statements quote your data for you, but for your query to work you need to do it this way:

```
$Search = "%$Search%";
$sel = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username LIKE :src");
$sel->bindValue(":src", $Search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Or directly:

```
$sel = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username LIKE :src");
$sel->bindValue(":src", "%$Search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

If you use `bindParam()` you need to use the first option as it needs a variable as a reference.

Comment: Thanks,but i think you should delete `{` brackets

Comment: Why?  You had them in your query, did you not want them?  I took them out, but since you had them I thought it was part of the data you were looking for.